Handling concurrent gift card purchases in ASP.NET Core API without causing database concurrency issues
I'm working on a gift card system where I have two main database tables:
GiftCards and ActivationCodes. Each gift card can have many pre-generated activation codes, and after a user purchases a gift card, they should receive one of the available activation codes.
// ActivationCode Entity
public class ActivationCode : BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public bool isUsed { get; set; } = false;
    public DateTime? ExpiresOn { get; set; }
    public bool IsExpired => DateTime.UtcNow >= ExpiresOn;

    public Guid GiftCardId { get; set; }
    public GiftCard GiftCard { get; set; }
    
    [Timestamp]
    public uint RowVersion { get; set; } // For Optimistic Concurrency Control
}

// GiftCard Entity
public class GiftCard : BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    public List<ActivationCode> ActivationCodes { get; set; }
}

//Purchase Gift Card
public async Task<GeneralResult<GiftCardPurchaseResult>> PurchaseGiftCard(
    Guid giftCardId, string userId)
{
    // 1. Retrieve the gift card information from the database
    // (checks if it's valid and available).

    // 2. Attempt to get an available activation code that hasn't been
    // used or expired, and isn't deleted.
    var getAvailableActivationCode = await _activationCodeRepository
        .GetTableNoTracking()
        .Where(gd => gd.GiftCardId == giftCardId && !gd.isUsed && !gd.IsDeleted && 
                     (DateTime.UtcNow < gd.ExpiresOn || gd.ExpiresOn == null))
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    // If no activation codes are available, return an error indicating
    // the gift card is out of stock.
    if (getAvailableActivationCode is null)
    {
        return GeneralResult<GiftCardPurchaseResult>
            .Failure("No activation codes are currently available "
                + "for this gift card.",
            HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
            new List<string> { GiftCardTransactionsErrorCode
                .ACTIVATION_CODES_NOT_AVAILABLE });
    }

    // 3. Retrieve the user's wallet balance and check if the balance
    // is sufficient for the purchase.

    using (var transaction = await _dataContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
    {
        try
        {
            // 4. Debit the user's wallet by deducting the gift card price.

            // 5. Mark the activation code as "used" by setting isUsed to true.
            getAvailableActivationCode.isUsed = true;

            // Update the activation code record in the database.
            await _activationCodeRepository.UpdateAsync(getAvailableActivationCode);

            // 6. Create a new entry in the GiftCardPurchases table to record
            // the purchase details.

            // Commit the transaction to apply changes to the database.
            await transaction.CommitAsync();

            // 7. Return a successful result with the purchase information.
            return GeneralResult<GiftCardPurchaseResult>.Success(purchaseResultInfo,
                "Gift card purchased successfully.");
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            // Handle concurrency issues (e.g., another transaction might have
            // updated the same activation code).
        }
    }
}

In my API (ASP.NET Core web API), when a user purchases a gift card, they are assigned one of the available, unused activation codes (isUsed == false and !IsExpired). The problem arises when concurrent requests for the same gift card result in multiple users being assigned the same activation code. This causes a DBConcurrencyException due to my optimistic concurrency control setup (RowVersion).
The main challenge is that the system doesn't need to wait for a specific activation code to be freed, as there are other available codes. However, I'm running into issues with concurrent transactions attempting to modify the same activation code.
What I've tried:
Pessimistic Locking: This isn't ideal in my case since there are other available activation codes, and we don't want the system to wait unnecessarily for a specific row to be unlocked.
Optimistic Concurrency Control: I've implemented optimistic concurrency using a RowVersion field. However, when two users try to select and mark the same activation code as used, the second transaction fails with a DbUpdateConcurrencyException. This forces retries, but I would rather avoid these concurrency conflicts altogether by ensuring that different codes are selected upfront.
Question :
How can I ensure that when concurrent users are purchasing the same gift card, they are always assigned different available activation codes without running into database concurrency issues? Is there a better pattern to handle this scenario where multiple activation codes are available?
Any insights into patterns or approaches to handle this kind of concurrency issue would be greatly appreciated!

The problem is transient, i.e. it should succeed on another attempt, so I would use Polly nuget package for retries.
Define policy that would retry operation on DbUpdateConcurrencyException:
private readonly RetryPolicy _policy = Policy
           .Handle<DbUpdateConcurrencyException>()
           .WaitAndRetry(3, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

and use it in your method:
public async Task<GeneralResult<GiftCardPurchaseResult>> PurchaseGiftCard(Guid giftCardId, string userId)
{
    return await _policy.Execute(async () => 
    {
        ... your code
    });
}


Thanks for the suggestion! Do you think it's possible to avoid these concurrency conflicts altogether by ensuring different activation codes are selected upfront? My concern is that retries might not be needed if I can prevent collisions in the first place.

One idea is to improve the selection process:
// 2. Attempt to get an available activation code that hasn't been
// used or expired, and isn't deleted.
var getAvailableActivationCode = await _activationCodeRepository
    .GetTableNoTracking()
    .Where(gd => gd.GiftCardId == giftCardId && !gd.isUsed && !gd.IsDeleted && 
                 (DateTime.UtcNow < gd.ExpiresOn || gd.ExpiresOn == null))
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

...by adding some form of randomization. Currently all concurrent purchase attempts are selecting the same gift card. I can't help you on how exactly you can add the randomization, because I am not familiar with the Entity framework. I guess using the Random class will not work:
    //...
    .OrderBy(gd => Random.Shared.Next())
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

...but there should be some other way compatible with the Entity framework.
